# Ros messages needed at different frequencies by two diff applications

Tags: ros, messages, synchronization

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi need a help

Suppose I have a message that publishes on a topic at a regular frequency. Two more applications (not necessary ros nodes) wants the messages but at different frequencies. For ex at 2 secs and 5 secs, what should be done?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/197297/ros-messages-needed-at-different-frequencies-by-two-diff-applications/) by [jennifer](https://answers.ros.org/users/2259/jennifer/) on ROS Answers with karma: 43 on 2014-11-12

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

http://wiki.ros.org/topic_tools/throttle allows you to do that.

---

Originally posted by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) with karma: 31395 on 2014-11-12

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [jennifer](https://answers.ros.org/users/2259/jennifer/) on 2014-11-13**:
Thanks!! For the prompt reply..

I also wanted to know, how about using parameter-service for this?
What do you suggest?